# How to prove $f(x) = \ln x$ continuous by proving first that $f(x)$ continuous at $1$, and then by using $\ln (xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, logarithms, functional-equations

I have a question concerning the proof of the continuity of $f(x) = \ln x$.

I read in a comment by Pedro Tamaroff to ncmathsadist's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314518/i-need-to-prove-the-continuity-of-fx-log-x-using-a-epsilon-delta-proof) that this can be proved in two steps:

1. first by proving that $f(x)$ is continuous at $1$,
2. and then by using $\ln (xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$.

However, I do not really see how to do it.

*How does it actually work?*

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Just wondering, why is this question so downvoted?

Comment: @Kolmin well, the title is not totally clear, but that's not enough of a reason really.

Comment: You should provide some more details perhaps about how you define the symbol $\log x$. The answer is crucially dependent on this information.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the feedback. I am editing the question accordingly.

Comment: Closely related question: [Functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and continuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567712/functional-equation-fxy-fxfy-and-continuity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have shown that $f=\ln$ is continuous at $1$.

---

We will use the following relation, that holds for any $x_0 > 0$
$$
\ln(x_0+h)
= \ln\left(x_0\left(1+\frac{h}{x_0}\right)\right)
= \ln x_0 + \ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x_0}\right). \tag{1}
$$

---

For an $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ proof: fix any $x_0>0$, and choose any $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\delta_1$ be such that
$$
\lvert\ln x - \ln 1\rvert \leq \varepsilon
$$
whenever $\lvert x-1\rvert \leq \delta_1$ (this exists by continuity of $\ln$ at $1$). Now, set $\delta \stackrel{\rm def}{=} x_0\delta_1$.

For any $x>0$ such that $\lvert x-x_0\rvert \leq \delta$, we have by (1)
$$\begin{align}
\lvert \ln x - \ln x_0\rvert
&= \lvert \ln (x_0+\underbrace{(x-x_0)}_{"h"}) - \ln x_0\rvert
= \left\lvert \ln\left( 1+\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right)\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \ln\left( 1+\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right) - \ln 1\right\rvert \leq \varepsilon
\end{align}$$
the last inequality since $\left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right\rvert \leq \frac{\delta}{x_0} = \frac{x_0\delta_1}{x_0} = \delta_1$.

So $\ln$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: is my answer wrong?

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. May I ask you why $\ln x_0 + \ln ( 1 + \frac{h}{x_0})$ implies continuity?

Comment: Read the rest: (1) is then used in the proof of continuity, to show the existence of a "good $\delta$" for arbitrary $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$. (I.e., (1) is not a full proof, it's the main building block **in** the proof that follows.)

Comment: I think I see. Hence (1) does not imply continuity straight away: it is rather something we use to establish continuity via $\epsilon -\delta$. But then, isn't it more straightforward to just prove the continuity of $f(x)$ by taking an arbitrary $x_0$ and then using $\epsilon -\delta$, without bothering with the initial extra step of establishing continuity at $1$?

Comment: [while you were editing, I was writing this comment]

Comment: It may be -- depending on how and if you manage to do so (the ease of which depends a lot on how the way $\ln$ was defined, which of its properties were established, and the set of tools/results you allow).

Comment: thus, you would say that this "double" step proof is actually more basic.

Comment: I will check the second part to see if it is everything clear to me. If not, maybe I will bother you again.

Comment: Again, depending on how $\ln$ was introduced, yes, it may be simpler to do it that way. (And regarding your latest comment: sure.)

Comment: ClementC. Idk. I was just guessing

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed, I do have some questions: **[a]** Why do we need to have established the continuity at $1$ to obtain equation (1)? **[b]** I can see every step with one exception, namely how to connect $$\displaystyle \left\lvert \ln\left( 1+\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right) - \ln 1\right\rvert $$ and $$ \displaystyle \left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}\right\rvert .$$ (mind that I see why the first expression is $\leq 0$ through the chain of implications you do from the second… I just don’t see how the two are related).

Comment: @Kolmin No need for continuity at $1$ to establish (1) (the phrasing of the first sentence is confusing, I may add a word to show better the structure). For your second question, write $u=1+\frac{x-x_0}{x_0}$, and then you have $\lvert \ln u - \ln 1\rvert$ and $\lvert u-1\rvert$. $\frac{x-x0}{x_0}=u-1$ is the thing that is bounded by $\delta_1$, for the continuity of $\ln$ at $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Superuseful and clear!

Comment: You're welcome!